# Functional reactive analog of Qt's QStateMachine

Tags: haskell, state-machine, frp

[QStateMachine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html) framework provides a nice declarative way to define stateful event based applications. I.e. then an event occurs it executes a callback (actually it fires a signal but this isn't sufficient) and performs a state transition according to the graph.

I haven't any actual experience with FRP, but by glance on reactive-banana's examples I didn't find if FRP can solve similar problem. For example 'Two counters' sample handles state by plain *if* and *accumB*.

So is there a clean and declarative way to fuse FSAs and FRP?

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me if I am missing the point on FSAs, but I believe `accumB` and friends can capture what you are aiming at, nicely and declaratively. In essence, individual states are values, and transitions are functions. A very simple example might begin with:

```
data ToggleState = Off | On deriving (Show)

toggle :: ToggleState -> ToggleState
toggle Off = On
toggle On  = Off

emergencyShutdown :: ToggleState -> ToggleState
emergencyShutdown _ = Off
```

(No good ideas for capturing the "open enum"-like schtick of `QState()` occur to me right now, though I guess it is not really a big deal, given the preference for strong typing of the typical Haskeller.)

Then, we set up the FRP network, capturing state as behaviors (i.e. time-varying values) and transitions as events:

```
-- Assuming eFlipSwitch and ePushShutdownButton are
-- defined terms of user input; say, through
-- bindings to your favourite UI library.
let
    eToggle :: Event t (ToggleState -> ToggleState)
    eToggle = toggle <$ eFlipSwitch

    eShutdown :: Event t (ToggleState -> ToggleState)
    eShutdown = emergencyShutdown <$ ePushShutdownButton

    -- By defining the behavior, we state once and for all the
    -- temporal evolution of the state in terms of the transitions.
    bState :: Behavior t ToggleState
    bState = accumB Off $ eToggle `union` eShutdown
```

There are many other possibilities. `IO` callbacks can be triggered by an event through `reactimate`. Guards, as described in the QStateMachine docs, can be done with `filterE` and related combinators. Animating UI elements can be readily done by the binding modules (look for `sink` in reactive-banana-wx or, for that matter, threepenny-gui). And so forth.